# Extract all but last field from a variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash, regex-negation

I have a file with lines similar to this:

```
01/01 THIS IS A DESCRIPTION 123.45
12/23 SHORTER DESC 9.00
11/16 DESC 1,234.00
```

Three fields: date, desc, amount.  The first field will always be followed by a space.  The last field will always be preceded by a space.  But the middle field will usually contain spaces.

I know bash/regex well enough to get the first and last fields (for example, `echo ${LINE##* }` or `cut -f1 -d\`).  But how do I get the middle field?  Essentially everything **except** the first and last fields.

Comment: Do you want everything except the last field or the middle field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]](.*)[[:space:]][^[:space:]]*$/\1/' file
THIS IS A DESCRIPTION
SHORTER DESC
DESC
```

Or with awk:

```
$ awk '{$1=$NF=""; sub(/^[ \t]*/,"")}1' file
# same output
```

You can also use `cut` and `rev` to delete the first and last fields:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f2- file | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev
# same output
```

Or GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP '^\H+\h\K(.*)(?=\h+\H+$)' file
# same output
```

Or, with a Bash loop and [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ while read -r line; do line="${line#* }"; echo "${line% *}"; done <file
# same output
```

Or, if you want to capture the fields as variables in Bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    date="${line%% *}"
    amt="${line##* }"
    line="${line#* }"
    desc="${line% *}"
    printf "%5s %10s \"%s\"\n" "$date" "$amt" "$desc"
done <file
```

Prints:

```
01/01     123.45 "THIS IS A DESCRIPTION"
12/23       9.00 "SHORTER DESC"
11/16   1,234.00 "DESC"
```

Comment: I guess, as per OP..he needs only the middle field ..not the last field which is the 'amount'.

Comment: @User123: typo; fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first and last fields, you can just extend the parameter expansion technique you referenced:

```
var=${var#* } var=${var% *}
```

A single `#` or `%` removes the shortest substring that matches the glob.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below one with `awk`:

```
awk '{$1="";$NF="";sub(/^[ \t]*/,"")}1' file_name
```

Comment: That will leave a leading space on the output, which is the leftover field separator between `$1` and the remaining fields.

Comment: Yeah, this was in my mind at the time of writing the answer, but thought it would be OK as per the requirement. Anyways, I've edited my answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: Probably better to use an anchor and include a tab: `sub(/ ^[ \t]*/,"")` or `sub(/ ^[[:blank:]]*/,"")`

Answer (score 0):

bash: read the line into an array of words, and pick out the wanted elements from the array

```
while read -ra words; do 
    date=${words[0]}
    amount=${words[-1]}
    description=${words[*]:1:${#words[@]}-2}

    printf "%s=%s\n" date "$date" desc "$description" amt "$amount"
done < file
```

outputs

```
date=01/01
desc=THIS IS A DESCRIPTION
amt=123.45
date=12/23
desc=SHORTER DESC
amt=9.00
date=11/16
desc=DESC
amt=1,234.00
```

This is the fun bit: `${words[*]:1:${#words[@]}-2}`

- take a *slice* of the words array, from index 1 (the 2nd element) for a *length* of "number of elements minus 2"
- the words will be joined into a single string with a  space separator.

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and scroll down a bit for the `${parameter:offset:length}` discussion.

---

If you want to use a regex in bash, then you can use capturing parentheses and the BASH_REMATCH array

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    if [[ $line =~ ([^[:blank:]]+)" "(.+)" "([^[:blank:]]+) ]]; then 
        echo "date=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 
        echo "desc=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" 
        echo "amt=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi
done < file
```

Same output as above.

Notice in the pattern that the spaces need to be quoted (or backslash-escaped)

Comment: Bash 4.3+ for the `${words[-1]}` negative array subscript... For older bash, `${words[${#words[@]}-1]}` for the last field. Nice one tho.

Comment: Right. Otherwise use the unreadable `amount=${words[${#words[@]}-1]}`